What are the locations of Zenobia's Gobstones in Hogwarts Legacy?
I'm currently busy with the Zenobia side quest where I need to find her Gobstones:

The location it takes me to is the transfiguration courtyard and then gives me a purple circle.
A hint is also to look at high places.
I'm looking around me, but I'm not seeing any Gobstones. How do they even look?
I'm casting "Revelio" everywhere also, but not seeing anything.
Where are these 6 Gobstones?

From what I understood, there's a bug: if you already picked one Gobstone, the hint for this Gobstone still reappears after a while. So you follow tutorials on the internet, you go to the exact location, the game tells you there's a Gobstone, but there isn't anymore. Just retrieve the others and you'll be fine.

Ah. I managed to find and figure it out. Each gobstone is in a different area.
1. Transfiguration Courtyard

2. Inside Trophy Room

3. Outside Trophy Room

4. Ravenclaw Tower

5. Near Divination Classroom

6. Outside Divination Classroom


This is what a Gobstone looks like:

And this is where to find the stones:

Transfiguration main courtyard, above eastern walkway
Entrance of Divination classroom, at the top of the staircase, up onto the chandelier
Room downstairs, on the wooden support on the left
Ravenclaw tower, grand staircase, on top of pillar on the right
Upstairs from the painting zone, there's a corridor with a bunch of armors, the stone is over an archway on the left
Room behind you, on top of a shelf

Here's a video tutorial:



